# Spark - How to count number of records by key

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloud

This is probably an easy problem but basically I have a dataset where I am to count the number of females for each country. Ultimately I want to group each count by the country but I am unsure of what to use for the value since there is not a count column in the dataset that I can use as the value in a groupByKey or reduceByKey. I thought of using a reduceByKey() but that requires a key-value pair and I only want to count the key and make a counter as the value. How do I go about this?

```
val lines = sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/desktop/file.txt")
val split_lines = lines.map(_.split(","))
val femaleOnly = split_lines.filter(x => x._10 == "Female")
```

Here is where I am stuck. The country is index 13 in the dataset also. 
The output should something look like this:
(Australia, 201000)
(America, 420000)
etc
Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to (temporarily) add a value?  You could essentially do it like word count and make all your KV pairs something like <female, 1> then reduceByKey and sum the values.  Or make the key <[female, australia], 1> then reduceByKey and sum to get the number of females in the specified country.  I'm not certain how to do this with scala, but with python+spark this is very easy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're nearly there! All you need is a [countByValue](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD):

```
val countOfFemalesByCountry = femaleOnly.map(_(13)).countByValue()
// Prints (Australia, 230), (America, 23242), etc.
```

(In your example, I assume you meant x(10) rather than x._10)

All together:

```
sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/desktop/file.txt")
    .map(_.split(","))
    .filter(x => x(10) == "Female")
    .map(_(13))
    .countByValue()
```

Comment: that's a great answer. How can I compute hashmap of a hashmap. That is I would like to have the grouping for every sex . Something like sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/desktop/file.txt")
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map(_(10))
  .map(_(13))
  .countByValue()

Comment: You shouldn't default to using countByValue, as that forces the whole map onto the master node (it returns a non-RDD). http://apachesparkbook.blogspot.com/2015/11/countbyvalue-example.html
Instead you should `femaleOnly.map((_(13), 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)`, which keeps all of the calculations and data on worker nodes.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered manipulating your RDD using the [Dataframes API](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html) ?

It looks like you're loading a CSV file, which you can do with [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv).

Then it's a simple matter (if your CSV is titled with the obvious column names) of:

```
import com.databricks.spark.csv._

val countryGender = sqlContext.csvFile("/home/cloudera/desktop/file.txt") // already splits by field
  .filter($"gender" === "Female")
  .groupBy("country").count().show()
```

If you want to go deeper in this kind of manipulation, here's the guide:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a *key*, it doesn't have to be in the file/database. For example:

```
val countryGender = sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/desktop/file.txt")
                .map(_.split(","))
                .filter(x => x._10 == "Female")
                .map(x => (x._13, x._10))    // <<<< here you generate a new key
                .groupByKey();
```

Comment: Could you finish this off with a reduce function to get counts of records by country?

Comment: this returns <key, iteratable>. You can map again something like -
val countryGenderCount = countryGender.map(lambda row : (row[0], len(row[1].data)))